# Getting a UUID (as a string) from a MySQL table, but is printing out as "true"?

Tags: java, mysql

```
    private UUID getClientID(String username) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT id FROM `client_table` WHERE username = ?";
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(rs.next());
        return UUID.fromString(String.valueOf(rs.next()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

So I printed rs.next out to console and it just says "true".. I'm trying to get the VALUE from the table but I think this is seeing if the value exists? Not sure what I've done wrong.. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returnvalue of `rs.next()` just tells you whether or not a row has been fetched. You need to use `rs.getString(1)` or something similar to get the actual values of the fetched row. (But you have to call `rs.next()` anyway!)